# Selenium PHP Web Driver (Facebook) issue

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ubuntu-14.04

I have a problem with [web driver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) startup for selenium on Ubuntu 14.04.
I've already installed [Oracle JDK](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) and [Selenium Standalone Server](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), also have no issue with running Selenium Standalone Server on Ubuntu 14.04 (I use cloud9 VDS).

But when I try to run [this example](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/community/example.php) an error occurs (Unable to create new service):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException' with message ' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/php-web-driver-test/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php on line 154 Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z' System info: host: 'user-selenium-6138185', ip: '173.18.0.42', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.80-c9', java.version: '1.8.0_171' Driver info: driver.version: unknown in /home/ubuntu/workspace/php-web-driver-test/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php on line 154 Call Stack: 0.0005 234144 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/php-web-driver-test/test-1.php:0 0.0020 307072 2. Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create() /home/ubuntu/workspace/php-web-driver-test/test-1.php:11 0.0030 387224 3. Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor->execute() /home/ubuntu/workspace/php-web-driver-test/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:126 0.1971 486960 4. Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException::throwException() /home/ubuntu/workspace/php-web-driver-test/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:320
```

Also there is some response from Selenium Server:

```
06:04:33.192 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3'
06:04:33.194 INFO [GridLauncherV3$1.launch] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2018-05-16 06:04:33.330:INFO::main: Logging initialized @566ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
06:04:33.641 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
06:04:42.085 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: Capabilities {browserName: chrome}
06:04:42.088 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

I don't know why such an error occurs, may be I have to force browser headless mode option or specify exact firefox or chrome location for web driver?

Comment: Running into the same issue on windows:https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5910